# Index of numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I split numpy.ndarray object:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

by test and train samples(with `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`). After that I need to identify, which elements of test sample correspond with elements of parent sample. `enter code here`

How to do this?

Comment: You seem to have pandas. So you could just sample and then split. The index lets you know where the sampled data came from. Ping me if you're interested in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the np.array to a dataframe:

```
In [13]: data  
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [14]: data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

then split the data and the associated index to test and train parts:

```
In [15]: train, test, train_index, test_index = train_test_split(data, data.index)

In [16]: train 
Out[16]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0  0  0

In [17]: test
Out[17]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5
2  0  0  0  0  0  0

In [18]: train_index 
Out[18]: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')

In [19]: test_index 
Out[19]: Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```

Then, you can access the train and test rows in the original dataframe as follows:

```
In [24]: data.loc[test_index, :]
Out[24]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5
2  0  0  0  0  0  0

In [25]: data.loc[train_index, :]
Out[25]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Note: I guess this is also what @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ proposed in the comments.